# Book which has different races and could use magic

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I'm trying to find the title of a teenager/young adult novel I read 10-15 years ago, I've tried every keyword I could think of and searched on google but I still couldn't find it. I only could remember small bits and will try my best to describe it.

I have the picture of the novel on my phone, well at least half of the novel and the quality is potato camera kind of quality. So I can't see the name of the author clearly but I think the author name starts with WC or VC (not V.C. Andrews) and the title is LEDG... something (still can't remember and can't find it on google). Important note on the title, i read it in my native language which is Indonesian so they might change the title and that "LEDG..." wouldn't help at all but i'm 100% sure that the author is not Indonesian.

[image]
<sub>*Click through for the full image.*</sub>

It's a magic-fantasy-war kind of novel. I think the main character was a young human male soldier, there are different races, I remember was a human-cat race(?) and maybe there was centaur race, not 100% sure though. There are magics, controlling water, fire, healing, summoning/teleporting magic, i remember the race that was summoned/teleported got green skin and considered elite race and that they bleed green. I'm not sure if every race could do magic but I remember a human-cat race controlling water on the sea and got possessed by the.. sea spirit(?).

I remember a plot where their... continent(?) were invaded by an invader from another continent across the sea, they came with tons of huge flying frigates/galleons with cannons who then bombarded cities and I think they were some kind of sea monsters race.

Comment: The [ISFDB only lists four authors](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=author_canonical&O_1=starts_with&TERM_1=V.+C.&C=AND&USE_2=author_canonical&O_2=exact&TERM_2=&USE_3=author_canonical&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=author_canonical&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=author_canonical&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=author_canonical&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=author_canonical&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Author) whose names begin with "V. C.".

Comment: @JohnRennie Even with this information i still couldn't find the book but thank you very much

Comment: I was thinking it looks like "WC", but the authors with short surnames after the 'WC' don't seem to have any fiction that meets the description. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=W.+C.&type=Name

Comment: I've similarly scanned ISFDB for books starting with "ledg", but no dice.

Comment: I'm not sure it is an 'E', the spacing doesn't look right. It's potentially an I or Y, or something stylised?

Comment: Using a image sharpener helps a little to figure out the title of the book. It seems to be "LIDO", or maybe "LIDG". https://imgur.com/a/jLxRWXx

Comment: @LAK holy smokes that's a lot of author, i will try to look at their works.. thanks mate

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yep i've tried everything now from ledg, lydg, lidg, nothing. thanks anyway, so nothing on title and nothing on author. my only hope now is to find someone who also read this novel..

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine yea I'm not sure either now, i was pretty sure that the title is LEDGEND but that word doesn't mean anything so I'm completely clueless. Damn potato phone camera

Comment: @Roberto Hmm I  tried to open the link you embed but I'm unable to but thanks I'll try to look around more with your suggestions.

Comment: I have tried to sharpen the image, mainly increasing brightness and contrast, and the title certainly begins with LEDG. The writer's name may start with "W." instead of "VC": The last name definitely begins with a J and looks to have four letters. The second letter may be an o, but could also be e or a.

Comment: I've tried every sort of enhancement I have and I can't pull anything useful out of that image, I agree @BeginTheBeguine that it does not look like an E after the first L. Truly frustrating.

Comment: We could make this one of those "identify every item on this picture" things.. top shelf has  Winnetou and Kara Ben Nemsi stories by Karl May, and next to that the Inheritance Cycle. Second row has the Godfather, a few unindentified, the first Septimus Heap novel, Koontz "Life Expectancy", "Pillars of the Earth" and a few more. Last row seems to be in German - three unknown, "Super Spannung" (A crime anthology), a crime novel by Heinz G. Konsalik, a German copy of HHGTTG, something unknown in red (published by the Knaur imprint judging by the design) and a Readers Digest Anthology.   Any more?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Hahaha spot on! next to the Godfather is called the Tunnels Series by Roderick Gordon and Brian Williams. Next to the Pillars of the Earth are some C.S. Lewis's ''The Chronicles of Narnia'' and couple of Agatha Christie's. The books on the 3rd row were my father's, i snatched it from him and just put it on my bookshelf lol. I still need the name of the book in the red circle though! :(

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen i'm pretty sure it started with LEDG too, if only i could read the name of the author.. Thanks for trying though

Comment: Can you think of any words in Indonesian that begin with LEDG?

Comment: Note that ISFDb doesn't have any matches, so either the title isn't English (ISFDb doesn't have great coverage of non-English works) or it's non-genre.

Comment: @Adamant none.. there is no Indonesian word that starts with Ledg.

Comment: @DavidW yes that might be the case, the title isn't English but it isn't Indonesian either LOL. Title from the picture won't help at all, author name might help but still unclear to me. My only hope is to find someone who recognize the plot i describe

Comment: @Midnight You might look at some of the topics on tvtropes (warning: addictive!) for centaurs or cat people. Maybe one of the listed races will sound familiar.

Comment: "Ledgend" seems to be a common mispelling of "Legend". So maybe look for a title with "Legend" in it.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for the advice.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Negative. I've tried that and the results i got is rather still a disappointment. But thanks for the idea, maybe I'll try again, harder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is *[Ledgard: Musuh Dari Balik Kabut](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1396766.Ledgard)* (which translates as *Ledgard: The Enemy From Behind the Fog*) by W.D. Yoga, published in 2005.

> Ifarett's three soldiers: Nash, Rhavi, and Deedek the Centaur have a special task, which is to take Vasthi, the daughter of the leader of the Kaloon nation, back to his home. After they died, it turned out that Ifarett was devastated by the invasion of foreigners coming from the western sky on an airplane boat. One by one, the Ledgard region was devastated by the invasion of the flying boat, following Ifarett.
>
> Nash, Rhavi and Deedek go to great lengths to convince all the nations in Ledgard that they cannot survive if they are still immersed in strife and vengeance among
> themselves. The risks they have to face are engaging in intrigue among the Sages, the harassing views of the inhabitants of Puri Pualam, distrust of the Ae Siri people, and the betrayal of the Centaurs.
>
> Why did Vasthi come all the way to Ifarett just to save Nash, Rhavi, and Deedek from the invasion of the flying
> boat? How did the trio convince the residents of Ledgard to unite? Why did the Centaurs choose their own direction? A myriad of questions will be answered with thousands of questions in this book. Don't be curious!

I think the cover matches well, and I believe the author is Indonesian.

Comment: Translation of the review suggests this matches the little plot recalled.  Nice find!

Comment: @mwarren - Well done, that surely has to be it! But no wonder this was so hard to find, with an old,  obscure Anglo-Saxon/German name as the title, and a synopsis written entirely in Indonesian.

Comment: @mwarren OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH! YOU'RE THE MAN! I am so grateful to you my dear saviour., This is indeed the title of the book i've been looking for yearsss! I can't believe someone finally able to tell me the title. Dang i was pretty sure the author wasn't Indonesian turns out i was wrong LOL, i always thought that it's an International book translated to Indonesian. Thank you very much to all who have tried to help, thank you again mwarren :)

Comment: @Midnight Glad to help, thanks to those who have improved my answer text. I was in a hurry. It wasn't easy as I don't speak the language.

Comment: When I was searching I found the shield-maiden Ladgerda, which may be where the author got the name. But they changed the middle letter so it was hopeless.

Comment: @Adamant - Ledgard is [an existing European surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledgard); it's just a very rare, little-known one.

Comment: Neat! Care to share how you found it?

Comment: @Jenayah It was deceptively simple in the end. The OP said they read it in Indonesian, the image seems to show the authors name is very short and that the title starts Ledg, so I googled "indonesian fantasy book" and the second result is a long list of 142 books from Goodreads which I went through until I saw entry 16 which was Ledgard by W.D. Yoga, which matched the title and short author name.

Comment: Sure, it is an existing surname, but I would be willing to bet that in a fantasy novel they were inspired by the famous Norse mythological character with an extremely similar name, rather than by a Peruvian swimmer or something.

Comment: @Adamant - The name is specifically of [Anglo-Saxon/German origin](https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Ledgard), and alot of fantasy stories are at least partly inspired by British or European history and mythology (King Arthur & Merlin, castles, dungeons, dragons, Robin Hood, viking invaders, etc). Tolkien was likely drawing heavily on that stuff when he created his Lord of the Rings universe, for example.

Comment: Yeah...Germanic stuff like tales of Viking warriors?

Comment: Vikings invaded both [Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_raids_in_the_Rhineland) and [Britain](https://www.history.org.uk/primary/resource/3867/the-vikings-in-britain-a-brief-history). Archaeologists have uncovered evidence of a [possible Viking city within Northern Germany](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/7/120711-lost-viking-town-germany-archaeology-science/).

Comment: Well, exactly....

Comment: What do you mean?